# Free cloud help desk for small open source team

Tags: gratis, cloud-service, issue-tracker, help-desk, support-tracker

### 1. About us

Our team:

- 2 developers
- 1 bot
- sometimes another developers small contribute to our repositories
- sometimes users create and comment their issues

At the time we use GitHub Issues for communications with users. But we want to learn and try in practice modern progressive methodologies and frameworks [**as Agile and Scrum**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/56169/264224), and it would be nice to have more powerful help desk.

We value our users, and we want them to be able to send issues in future without let or hindrance. Help desk not must be only for developers.

---

### 2. Requirements

1. Free license possibility for open source non-commercial projects ([**JitBit**](https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/purchase/) and, possibly, [**Faveo**](https://github.com/ladybirdweb/faveo-helpdesk/issues/732) have only commercial versions)
2. Cloud version, not self-hosted ([**Trac**](https://trac.edgewall.org/browser) only self-hosted)
3. Agile, Scrum or another progressive/perspective methodologies/frameworks integration
4. Permissions as in GitLab/BitBucket/GitHub Issues ([**I have problems with JIRA**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54269250/5951529)):

   1. For guests (anyone in Internet): read-only any issue
   2. For any registered user: create and comment issues
5. Number of users:

   1. Permission: create and comment issues — not less than 50 (YouTrack free version [**only 3 users support**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-51288#focus=streamItem-27-3261387-0-0))
   2. More advanced permissions — not less than 10
6. API
7. Backup possibility for issue trackers
8. Any non plain text markup for issues

---

### 3. Desirable requirements

1. Slack or another powerful chat integration
2. Python tools for issue creating and getting via API
3. [**Makrdown GFM**](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown) support
4. More powerful features it would be nice
5. Open source

Comment: Do you want to have control on who can register as a user?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, I want, that anyone Internet user can register on help desk → create or comment issues. No manually admin confirmation, who can write issues and who not. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, `50` — max issue reporters, `10` — max team members; see 2.5 item. Any Internet users may be in the number `50`. I think, that your header edition distorts the meaning of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to edit the title, in the current situation it is too broad. Cheers!